# How to bring audio from microphone to speaker on Android?

Tags: android

My problem is when I talk into the microphone, I want my sound to go to speaker of the phone which has Android OS. I think "MediaPlayer" class can't do it. Do you have any way?

Comment: Do you simply want to record voice ?

Comment: yes. I do. I want to capture the mic input and play it at the same time. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not clear in which scenario you are going to do this but however it is possible to do using `AudioManager`, you can set your modes and audio services. For more details refer this link :

[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)